# Center image on jQuery Slider in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an jQuery Content Slider. But i have an problem, where tall images is stretch. Isn't it possible to center the image. Some says that i need to set the overflow to hidden. But it doesn't make any differences. 
Best regard Morten Starck

The html code:

```
 <ul class="bxslider">
<li>
  <img id="propImageSliderLarge" src="http://billeder.edc.dk/edcmedia/2012/04-April/04/4fac343a-5d4b-4aab-8205-f57f165bc484_Size687x458.jpg"/></li>
<li>
  <img id="propImageSliderLarge" src="http://billeder.edc.dk/edcmedia/2012/04-April/04/7bdfb0cc-47ec-4afa-9fc7-aa2cbb9d43a0_Size687x458.jpg"/></li>
<li>
  <img id="propImageSliderLarge" src="http://billeder.edc.dk/edcmedia/2012/04-April/04/aad1d457-285d-42e3-8e68-e243bd2988d4_Size687x458.jpg"/></li>
<li>
  <img id="propImageSliderLarge" src="http://billeder.edc.dk/edcmedia/2012/04-April/04/768fda69-af61-4322-a60b-012040d78384_Size687x458.jpg"/></li>
<li>
  <img id="propImageSliderLarge" onload="FixImages(true)" src="http://www.blog.designsquish.com/images/uploads/victorian-flatbush-old-hous_thumb.jpg" /></li>
```

And the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
  });
</script>
```

and the CSS code:

```
#propImageSliderLarge {
  width: 530px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two things you're doing wrong here.  First, you're using the same ID for multiple elements, this isn't valid. I think you intended to use CSS classes. Second, you're setting the `width` and `height` attributes of the `IMG` tag, when in fact you should set these attributes on the container (in this case the `LI`). Try the following:

**Change your markup to this**

```
<li class="propImageSliderLarge">
    <img src="http://billeder.edc.dk/edcmedia/2012/04-April/04/4fac343a-5d4b-4aab-8205-f57f165bc484_Size687x458.jpg"/>
</li>
```

**Change your CSS to this**

```
.propImageSliderLarge {
    width: 530px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; /* this will centre your image in the LI */
}
```

**Update the image dimension if larger than LI container**

This script assumes variables set for `containerWidth` and `containerHeight` so just set these to whatever your `LI` container size is and it'll resize the images to the max constraints of the container so you can see the entire image.

```
function resizeImage(img) {
    var imgWidth = parseInt($(img).width());
    var imgHeight = parseInt($(img).height()); 

    if (imgWidth > containerWidth || imgHeight > containerHeight) {
        $(img).width(containerWidth);
        $(img).height(containerHeight);
    }
}​
```

Comment: Is it's also possible to zoom out so in tall image is showed i full?

Comment: @mortenstarck sorry I don't understand what you're getting at here? Do you mean you want a thumbnail in the slider, but when clicked on (or some other event) it will zoom to a larger view of the image? If so, then this is a different question.

Comment: No. I mean then an very tall image is loaded, it's not possible to see very much of the image. So is it possible to zoom out, so i can see the hole picture. Hope that's more understandable.

Comment: @mortenstarck ah right of course, I understand now. In cases where the size of the image exceeds the size of the container (`LI` in our case) then you can use script to set the height / width of the `IMG` to the size of the `LI` - this will resample your image to the size of the container allowing you to view (albeit a skewed / squashed) version - have updated with a ROUGH script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the attribute id to attribute class. Id means Identifier, and as the name goes, two things cannot have same identifier. To center the images, give an id to ul tag and add following css:

text-align: center;

Try this...not sure if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the slider in onload and check it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'fade',
      captions: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

otherwise, you can use anyone suitable slider in http://bxslider.com/examples